How can I make SwiftData models unique within a collection?
Background
I am learning how to use the SwiftData framework for data storage in SwiftUI iOS apps.
I have found that I cannot use a Swift Set within a SwiftData model, but I am still looking to achieve set-like functionality.
Example code
To help illustrate my problem, I have created the following SwiftData models:
@Model class Computer {
    // Computers cannot share identical serialNumbers
    @Attribute(.unique) let serialNumber: String
    // A Computer can have many directories
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var directories: [Directory]
    
    init(name: String, directories: [Directory] = []) {
        self.name = name
        self.directories = directories
    }
}

@Model class Directory {
    // Each Directory on a Computer must have a unique path,
    // but Computers can have Directories with identical paths as other Computers (not working).
    @Attribute(.unique) let path: String
    // A Directory can have many files
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var files: [File]
    
    init(path: String, files: [File] = []) {
        self.path = path
        self.files = files
    }
}

I expect my code to let me:

Create two computers: Computer "A" and Computer "B"
Create a "/home" directory on each computer
Each "/home" directory is a different instance of Directory (so each computer can hold different files in "/home")

With this code, I can add "/home" to Computer "A", but when I try to add a "/home" directory on Computer "B", I get a crash.
Alternate code
Alternatively, I can change the directories relationship in my Computer model to specify an inverse relationship:
@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Directory.computer) var directories: [Directory]

and add this line to my Directory model:
var computer: Computer?

Now, I can add the "/home" directory on Computer "B", but it will delete the Directory with the same path from Computer "A".
Question
Why does this happen? Is there any way in SwiftData to ensure uniqueness within a specific collection, rather than across the entire app?
I failed to find any SwiftData example code or documentation about how to set up a relationship like this.

Perhaps think about it the other way around? Each directory exists on only one computer, whereas computers have many directories. Why not let the directory refer to the computer that "owns" it?

@Ron Interesting idea—I kind of tried this with inverse relationships. But I'm not sure how this approach addresses how the system should enforce that two Directories with identical paths do not exist on the same Computer.

How about appending the computer id to the path and let SwiftData enforce uniqueness? (Think about it as like a URL.)

That might work for helping enforce uniqueness, but it makes retrieving/parsing the directory path more complex.
I could add an extra member to the model to hold the un-appended path, but then I'm working to keep the two values in sync.
Is SwiftData really missing the ability to define a relationship like this?If so, I suppose this is a decent workaround

A more correct design imo is to have a one-to-many relationship for Directory to itself since a directory might contain files and other directories

As for making an object unique within a collection I don’t think you can make SwiftData handle that for you so you will need some custom code for it

Hopefully SwiftData adds some functionality and/or documentation around this. But for now, I think both of you are right that I'll have to enforce uniqueness myself. I appreciate the ideas.
